# How to rasterize point data using average value per cell (not replace or add)

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, rioxarray, geocube

I have a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` containing point observations that I would like to rasterize into a grid with a certain resolution, such that, for cells that contain multiple observations, the resulting grid cell value is the **average** value of the contained points.

In an ideal world I'd use `geocube.api.core.make_geocube` due to its ease of use. My current code looks something like this.

```py
import json

import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from shapely.geometry import box, mapping, Point

# global bounding box
bbox = (-180, -90, 180, 90)

# some random points
points = [Point(np.random.uniform(-180, 180), np.random.uniform(-90, 90)) for _ in range(1000)]

# some random data values
data = np.random.rand(1000)

# create GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'data': data}, geometry=points, crs='EPSG:4326')

grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=gdf,
    measurements=[column],
    resolution=(-0.5, 0.5),
    geom=json.dumps(mapping(box(*bbox))),
)
```

The problem here, if I understand correctly, is that `geocube`'s default `rasterize_function` (`geocube.rasterize.rasterize_image`) utilizes `rasterio.enums.MergeAlg` as the only options for merging values that coincide in a single cell, i.e. GDAL's REPLACE or ADD methods. I'll add that in my case I don't want to do any interpolation of missing values.

Is there a way to easily implement a custom AVERAGE merge algorithm in this case, or will I need to do it all manually, e.g. with `rioxarray` or other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I ended up implementing this semi-manually without `geocube`**:

```py
import os
from typing import Union

import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.transform import from_origin


def rasterize_points(
    points: np.ndarray, res: Union[int, float], bbox: tuple
) -> np.ndarray:
    """Rasterize points into a grid with a given resolution.

    Args:
        points (np.ndarray): Points to rasterize, with columns (x, y, value) (for
            geographic coordinates, use (lon, lat, value))
        res (Union[int, float]): Resolution of the grid
        bbox (tuple): Bounding box of the grid

    Returns:
        np.ndarray: Rasterized grid
    """
    width = int((bbox[2] - bbox[0]) / res)
    height = int((bbox[3] - bbox[1]) / res)

    rast = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.float32)
    count_array = np.zeros_like(rast)
    for x, y, value in points:
        col = int((x - bbox[0]) / res)
        row = int((bbox[3] - y) / res)
        rast[row, col] += value
        count_array[row, col] += 1

    # Avoid division by zero
    count_array[count_array == 0] = 1

    # Calculate the average
    rast = rast / count_array

    return rast


def write_raster(
    raster: np.ndarray, res: Union[int, float], bbox: tuple, filename: os.PathLike
) -> None:
    """Write a raster to a GeoTIFF file.

    Args:
        raster (np.ndarray): Raster matrix to write
        res (Union[int, float]): Resolution of the raster
        bbox (tuple): Bounding box of the raster
        filename (os.PathLike): Path to the output file
    """
    width = int((bbox[2] - bbox[0]) / res)
    height = int((bbox[3] - bbox[1]) / res)

    with rio.open(
        filename,
        "w",
        driver="GTiff",
        height=height,
        width=width,
        nodata=0,
        count=1,
        dtype=rio.float32,
        crs="EPSG:4326",
        transform=from_origin(bbox[0], bbox[3], res, res),
        compress="zstd",
    ) as dst:
        dst.write(raster, 1)

# Set bounding box and output resolution
bbox = (-180, -90, 180, 90)
res = 0.01

# Some random points in (lon, lat, value) format
points = [(np.random.uniform(-180, 180), np.random.uniform(-90, 90), np.random.rand()) for _ in range(1000)]

# Rasterize to a grid
grid = rasterize_points(points, res, bbox)

# Write to file
write_raster(grid, res, bbox, "path/to/raster.tif")
```